# Issue with testing an app on 64-bit hardware

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb

I'm trying to test my app with new guidelines about 64-bits librairies, using this link:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#test_your_app_on_64-bit_hardware

When trying to use adb to "force" one library, I have this problem :

```
$ adb install --abi armeabi-v7a zzz.apk
zzz.apk: 1 file pushed. 2.3 MB/s (7359404 bytes in 3.087s)
Error: Unknown option: --abi
```

What is installed on my MacBook:
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
Version 4986621

any ideas with this problem ?

kind regards,
PaBX

Comment: Seems to work for me with ADB 1.0.36 on Windows. So maybe something happened in a later platform-tools release, or perhaps the MacOS version is broken.

Comment: thanks Michael... well I will make tests with my son's computer.

Comment: I don't think adb actually has anything to do with this. `install` causes adb to invoke `pm install`, which is the thing not handling the `--abi` argument. Maybe that flag isn't available on older devices?